# How to dynamically change the value of the text based on the document.title

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have a project with next.js page router

[image]

I'm making a page transition with framer-motion and I want the paragraph to have the value of the current `document.title`

It works fine the issue is let's say if I'm on the about page and the title is about when I move to contact the paragraph animation will show about then contact, and if I went from contact to home I will see contact then home

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { text, curve, translate } from './animation';

const anim = (variants: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    return {
        variants,
        initial: "initial",
        animate: "enter",
        exit: "exit"
    }
}

export default function Curve({ children, backgroundColor }: { children: React.ReactNode, backgroundColor: string }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<{ width: number | null, height: number | null }>({ width: null, height: null });
    const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        function resize() {
            setDimensions({
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            })
        }
        resize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", resize)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setPageTitle(document.title || null);
        const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
            setPageTitle(document.title || null);
        };
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        };
    }, [router.events]);

    return (
        <div className='page curve' style={{ backgroundColor }}>
            <div style={{ opacity: dimensions.width == null ? 1 : 0 }} className='background' />
            <motion.p className='route' {...anim(text)}>
                {pageTitle}
            </motion.p>
            {dimensions.width != null && <SVG {...dimensions} />}
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

const SVG = ({ height, width }: { height: number | null, width: number | null }) => {

    if (width == null || height == null) {
        return null;
    }

    const initialPath = `
        M0 300 
        Q${width / 2} 0 ${width} 300
        L${width} ${height + 300}
        Q${width / 2} ${height + 600} 0 ${height + 300}
        L0 0
    `

    const targetPath = `
        M0 300
        Q${width / 2} 0 ${width} 300
        L${width} ${height}
        Q${width / 2} ${height} 0 ${height}
        L0 0
    `

    return (
        <motion.svg {...anim(translate)}>
            <motion.path {...anim(curve(initialPath, targetPath))} />
        </motion.svg>
    )
}
```